# How to bulk insert in Mongoose cursor.eachAsync?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried several solutions to get this working but all failed. I am reading the Mongo DB docs using cursor.eachAsync() and converting some doc fields. I need to move these docs to another collection after conversion.My idea is that after 1000 docs are processed, they should be bulk-inserted into the destination collection. This works good until the last batch of records which are less than 1000. To phrase the same problem differently, if the number of records are <1000 then they are not inserted.

**1. First version - bulk insert after async()**

Just like any other code, I should have docs < 1000 in bulk object after async() and should be able to insert. But I find bulk.length is 0. (I have removed those statements in the code snippet below).

```js`async function run() {

```
await mongoose.connect(dbPath, dbOptions);
const cursor = events.streamEvents(query, 10);
let successCounter = 0;
let bulkBatchSize = 1000;
let bulkSizeCounter = 0;
let sourceDocsCount = 80;
var bulk = eventsConvertedModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
await cursor.eachAsync((doc) => {
    let pPan = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getTokenSwap(doc.panTokenIdentifier, doc._id)
            .then((swap) => {
                resolve(swap);
            });                
    });

    let pXml = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xmlObject;
        getXmlObject(doc)
            .then(getXmlObjectToken)
                    .then((newXmlString) => { 
                        resolve(newXmlString);
                    })
                    .catch(errFromPromise1 => {
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });

    Promise.all([pPan, pXml])
        .then(([panSwap, xml]) => {
            doc.panTokenIdentifier = panSwap;
            doc.eventRecordTokenText = xml;
            return doc;
        })
        .then((newDoc) => {
            successCounter++;
            bulkSizeCounter++;
            bulk.insert(newDoc);
            if (bulkSizeCounter % bulkBatchSize == 0) {
                bulk.execute()
                    .then(result => {
                        bulkSizeCounter = 0;
                        let msg = "Conversion- bulk insert =" + result.nInserted;
                        console.log(msg);
                        bulk = eventsConvertedModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
                        Promise.resolve();
                    })
                    .catch(bulkErr => {
                        logger.error(bulkErr);
                    });
            }
            else {
                Promise.resolve();
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
console.log("outside-async=" + bulk.length); // always 0
console.log("run()- Docs converted in this run =" + successCounter);
process.exit(0);
```

}`

**2. Second version** (track expected number of iterations and after all iterations, change batch size to say 10). 
Result - The batch size value changes but it's not reflected in bulk.insert. The records are lost.

**3. Same as 2nd but insert one record at a time** after bulk inserts are done.

```js

```
let d = eventsConvertedModel(newDoc);
d.isNew = true;
d._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
d.save().then(saved => {
   console.log(saved._id)
   Promise.resolve();
  }).catch(saveFailed => {
     console.log(saveFailed);
     Promise.resolve();
 });
```

```

Result - I was getting DocumentNotFound error, so I added `d.isNew = true`. But for some reason only few records get inserted and many of them get lost.

I have also tried other variations using the number of expected bulk insert iterations. Finally, I changed the code to write to file (one doc at a time) but I am still wondering if there is any way to make write to DB make work.

**Dependencies:**
Node v8.0.0
Mongoose 5.2.2